# Web API não retorna JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

[image: retorno]fiz uma web api c# onde por padrão retorna xml, tentei de vários métodos da internet transformar esse retorno para json mas quando faço uma requisição continua vindo em xml, alguém poderia ajudar?

método que apresenta o resultado:

```
 // GET: api/OINV/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(OINV))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOINV(int id)
    {
        OINV oINV = db.OINV.Find(id);
        if (oINV == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(oINV);
    }
```

webapiconfig.cs

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Web API routes
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

Comment: Onde há algum retorno aí?

Comment: Posta o método que retorna o valor

Comment: Olá Leandro, obrigado por responder, estarei editando e colocando o retorno

Comment: Apresente o método que está retornando o xml

Comment: @LeandroAngelo alterado leandro, de uma olhada.

Comment: Tentou invés de `text/html` por `application/json`?

Comment: já @Barbetta, ele até carrega em json mas em 1 segundo pisca e volta pra xml, bem estranho.

Comment: `[Produces("application/json")]` antes a declaração da sua classe de controller já não resolve?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo tentei aqui mas da erro de namespace could not be found

Comment: Ok... de que versão você está falando e de qual classe a sua controller está herdando

Comment: @LeandroAngelo web api entity framework, criei a controller com entity framework, o db também

Comment: controller com entity framework? desculpe nunca ouvi falar disso

Comment: Isso, clico com o botão direito na pasta controller > add>controller dai seleciono de qual tabela do banco criar. Ele cria o crud sozinho

Comment: ok.... mas a controller não herda do entity framework, certo? e quanto a versão, eu me refiro a do asp.net

Comment: Bom, estou longe do pc agr mas amanhã posso trazer essa informação

Comment: Bom dia, @LeandroAngelo versão 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade não tem com o que se preocupar, a **ASP.NET Web API 2** com o **Framework 4.X** vai serializar as respostas tanto como **XML**, quanto **JSON** de acordo com o que for definido na requisição. Não deveria se preocupar em como esse conteúdo está aparecendo no browser porque o Web API não é apresentar o conteúdo para a leitura de um usuário, mas sim servir de interface para a comunicação entre aplicações.

[Documentação Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Ou seja por padrão ele já está atendendo os clients que pretentendem desserializar o conteúdo tanto em `XML` quanto `JSON`. Mas, se você quer restringir a sua aplicação para retornar apenas no formato JSON você pode fazer como sugerido pelo @Barbetta e [remover o MediaType do xml da lista da formatadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/407429/36915).

Agora, se a questão é apenas para você visualizar os dados no browser para testes e "documentação" você pode implementar recursos que são especializados para isso, como o [Swagger](https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/).

Mas o que eu realmente recomendaria, uma vez que está começando uma aplicação nova, seria já trabalhar com a versão do ASP.Net Core que só vai lhe trazer benefícios ([tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)).

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**
[image: Requisição pelo Postman]

Comment: Olá Leandro! Muito obrigado pela resposta e explicação, realmente não sabia que não teria problema no retorno. Agradeço também pelas dicas passadas!

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é remover o `SupportedMediaType` XML

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //Outras Configurações
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
        .Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml"));
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo também amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar as seguintes linhas ao método `Register`:

```
 config.Formatters.Clear();
 config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Vi um cara com o mesmo problema aqui no stackoverflow e ele fez isso: [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome/26068063#26068063)

Ele apaga todos os formatadores da web api e em seguida adiciona o suporte para formatação em json

Comment: Olá Michael, infelizmente não deu certo.